# Published private app is not visible on mobile play store

Tags: android

I have published my app to production directly without doing the alpha or beta testing. I see that the app is published and is visible at below link:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.henshawsuk

The app is not visible on the mobile play store.
Please help me on making the app visible for mobile or tablet device.

Thanks,
Monika

Comment: If it's private, the device needs to be logged into an eligible account.

Comment: Hi @Monika, what do you mean about private? BTW, the link you have put does not work.